# How to use a custom post type as a taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy

I have a custom post type for adding books and a custom post type for adding reviews and I want when I add a review to associate it with a specific book. I don't know what is the best way to do this. I want to know if it's possible to use a custom post type as a taxonomy for another one and how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use a `custom post type` as a taxonomy. What you can do is create a `relation field` on the `review` post-type with `ACF` (or write your own), and add the `book` which the review belongs to.

There is absolutely no need for a taxonomy here, and definitely not the way you want to use it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a custom post type as a taxonomy, but you can have the same taxonomy on 2 custom post. If you register the ID of the book on your review, you can make relationship between both, that's what you want to do ?

Comment: That's what I want to do but I am very new to wordpress and I am a little confuse

Comment: To register the same taxonomy on 2 custom post type, you have to do this register_taxonomy( 'taxonomy_name', array('books','review'), $args_taxonomy ); that's help you ?

Comment: you can get more info about how to declare this on wordpress codex https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a Custom field? You can have the book post type, use "review" as key, then you write the review's value.

Here is the link, so you can understand better
https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields

Answer (score -1):

Add this code in **functions.php** file after update category option will display

```
/****mybooks_args category in posttype***/
$mybooks_args = array(
    'labels' => array(
    'name' => 'mybooks Items',
    'singular_name' => 'mybooks Item'),
    'description' => 'Allows you to build custom mybooks items and link them to categories',
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-schedule',
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'menu_position' => 20,
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
    'has_archive' => true,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'mybooks-item'),
    'can_export' => true
);

/* http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type */
register_post_type('mybooks', $mybooks_args);

$categories_labels = array(
    'label' => 'Categories',
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'query_var' => true
);

/*  Register taxonomies for extra post type capabilities */
register_taxonomy('mybooks_categories', 'mybooks', $categories_labels);
/****./mybooks_args category in posttype***/
```